# Why does withCallingHandlers still stops execution?

Tags: r, error-handling

It seems that `withCallingHandlers` doesn't actually catch the error the way that `tryCatch` does and the script still stops executing.

Compare the snippet with `tryCatch` where both "before" and "after" are printed:

```
f1 <- function() {
  cat("before tryCatch\n")
  tryCatch({
      stop("this is an error!")
    },
    error = function(cond) {
      print(cond$message)
    }
  )
  cat("after tryCatch\n")
}
```

With the same snippet with `withCallingHandlers` that doesn't print "after" and stops execution:

```
f2 <- function() {
  cat("before tryCatch\n")
  withCallingHandlers({
      stop("this is an error!")
    },
    error = function(cond) {
      print(cond$message)
    }
  )
  cat("after tryCatch\n")
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Some context**

I'd like to use `withCallingHandlers` to analyze the call stack at the point where the error occurs using `sys.calls()`.

According to [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html) that should be possible:

> The handlers in `withCallingHandlers()` are called in the context of the call that generated the condition whereas the handlers in `tryCatch()` are called in the context of `tryCatch()`.

Comment: It seems that wrapping `withCallingHandlers` with `tryCatch` resolves the problem, but it seems a bit ugly.

Comment: Simply said the error parameter in `withCallingHandlers` is used to as to signal an error to the function but does not establish an error handler that recovers from the error. This can only be achieved by using `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Calling handlers provide a way of 'touching' a condition on the way through, maybe logging an error to a file before signalling the user in an interactive session.

Calling handlers can be used to 'muffle' warnings, messages, or errors if the calling handler doesn't actually return.  You can make a calling handler not return using restarts -- surround the code that you'd like to continue executing in a call to `withRestarts()`, and invoke the restart in the handler:

```
f2 <- function() {
  cat("before tryCatch\n")
  withCallingHandlers({
      withRestarts({
          stop("this is an error!")
      }, muffleStop=function() {
          message("'stop' muffled")
      })
    },
    error = function(cond) {
      print(cond$message)
      invokeRestart("muffleStop")
    }
  )
  cat("after tryCatch\n")
}
```

It's more usual that the restarts are established in one chunk of code (like in the built-in function `warning`) and invoked in a completely independent chunk of code (like the built-in function `suppressWarnings`:

```
> warning
function (..., call. = TRUE, immediate. = FALSE, noBreaks. = FALSE, 
    domain = NULL) 
{
        ##
        ## ...
        ##
        withRestarts({
            .Internal(.signalCondition(cond, message, call))
            .Internal(.dfltWarn(message, call))
        }, muffleWarning = function() NULL)
        ##
        ## ...
        ##
}
<bytecode: 0x51a4730>
<environment: namespace:base>
> suppressWarnings
function (expr) 
{
    ops <- options(warn = -1)
    on.exit(options(ops))
    withCallingHandlers(expr, 
        warning = function(w) invokeRestart("muffleWarning"))
}
<bytecode: 0x35c2a60>
<environment: namespace:base>
```