# `withCallingHandlers` inside `tryCatch` creates uncatchable error

Tags: r, error-handling

I need to convert a warning to an error to be able to handle it further upstream (warnings are swallowed somewhere in the middle, over which I have no control; errors are not). To do this, I’m doing the following:

```
warning_to_error = function (expr)
    withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = stop)
```

This works great:

```
> warning_to_error(warning('foobar'))
Error in withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = stop) : foobar
```

Unfortunately, this makes the error *completely* uncatchable:

```
> try(warning_to_error(warning('foobar')))
Error in withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = stop) : foobar
```

[In my real situation](https://github.com/mschubert/clustermq/issues/22), there are several layers between my `warning_to_error` and the `try` (including the logic that muffles warnings). How can I make the error raised by my calling handler catchable? Unfortunately I cannot use restarts as described [in another Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32167959/1968) because `stop` doesn’t define a restart, and I once again have no control over the code doing the catching anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should tell you what is happening with your definition of `warning_to_error`:

````
> tryCatch(warning_to_error(warning('foobar')), condition = print)
<simpleWarning in withCallingHandlers(expr, warning = stop): foobar>```
````

As the documentation for `stop` says, when you call `stop` with a condition, that condition is signalled to look for handlers, which means `warning` handlers in this case. If you want an error handler to be invoked you need to signal an error condition. That is what happens when you set `options(warn = 2)` for example. So you need something like

```
warning_to_error1 <- function (expr)
    withCallingHandlers(expr,
                        warning = function(w)
                            stop("(converted from warning) ",
                                 conditionMessage(w)))
```

That gives you

```
> tryCatch(warning_to_error1(warning('foobar')),
+          error = function(e) print("Got it"))
[1] "Got it"
```

Ideally we should provide a condition class and constructor for warnings converted to errors and use that internally for `warn = 2`

Comment: Thanks, this makes perfect sense. I actually attempted to do just that (= printing/returning the condition to inspect it) but my attempts failed because it simply didn’t occur to me that the class would be anything other than `error`. Duh.

Comment: It would be even greater if I could somehow spoof the call stack information. Unfortunately I’m unable to achieve this even when using `eval`, executed in the `parent.frame()` of `warning_to_error`: the stack trace invariably ends in the `eval` itself. I’m guessing this isn’t possible?

Comment: Create an error condition object and store the result of `sys.calls` in it before passing it to `stop`.

Comment: Awesome. That only fixes the display and not the actual stack trace but I can live with that (and it’s arguably the desired result anyway).